# I get "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" even though I'm not working on a file

Tags: python

I am getting the error when I run this code.

`import_csv` successfully returns a `<_csv.reader object at 0x10e1f8f50>`. The problem is with `exclude_regex_users(name_entries)` which isn't even working with a file.

Does anyone see a problem with my code?

```
def import_csv(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file) as csvfile:
        name_entries = csv.reader(csvfile)
    return name_entries


def exclude_regex_users(name_entries):
    pulled_names = []
    r = re.compile(r'\w+\+\d+@trellis\.law')

    for name in name_entries:
        n = r.match(name)
        if n:
            pulled_names.append(n.group())

    print(pulled_names)


def main():
    name_entries = import_csv('users.csv')
    exclude_regex_users(name_entries)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
  File "doodle.py", line 42, in main
    exclude_regex_users(name_entries)
  File "doodle.py", line 32, in exclude_regex_users
    for name in name_entries:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: `with open(csv_file) as csvfile` is working with a file.

Comment: The moment you reach the next line, the `return name_entries` line, `csvfile` is closed. It is not kept open by the `csv.reader()` object. So now you have a reader that if used tries to read from a closed file.

Comment: Note that `name_entries` is the `csv.reader()` object, which only reads from the file you give it when you try to loop over it, with `for nam in name_entries`.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion lies in how `csv.reader()` objects work? They don't read the whole file into memory and produce the CSV rows up front. That'd be very inefficient. The `csv.reader()` object will read from the open file *on your behalf* as you try to loop over the reader to get at the rows. So a closed file is really a problem there.